# Grep with a variable

Tags: bash, variables, search, grep

I would like to `grep` a number of documents by using a set of search terms and to specify the number of characters after match. Here is what I tried

```
grep  -F -o -P "$(<search.txt).{0,4}" foo.txt
```

but I get the message 'grep: conflicting matchers specified' because `-F` and '-oP' cannot be combined. It does not work with '-E' either.

Comment: What are the contents of `search.txt` exactly? What sort of match are you trying to do exactly? `{0,4}` is a modifier for the atom directly before it (so to match whatever you get out of `search.txt` and four more characters you need `.{0,4}`).

Comment: How about trying to handcraft a grep command that matches any of "dog" or "cat" followed by four letters, and then seeing if you can turn a search.txt containing "dog" and "cat" into that command.

Comment: `search.txt` contains a list of terms and names. You're right with `.{0,4}` I made a mistake above, I'll correct it.

Comment: @that other guy, matching is not a problem, the search does match search terms properly but it shows the whole lines and I want to see only zero or four letters following my search terms.

Comment: @user3635159 does that mean you were able to handcraft a grep command that matches any of "dog" or "cat" followed by 0 or 4 letters? What was it? If you put an `echo` in front of that command and this command, do you find a difference?

Comment: You need to provide some sample data in question and your expected output.

Comment: Do you have any control over the contents of search.txt or can it be anything? For instance, if you were pretty certain it would contain only alphabetics you could just forget the -F without difficulty...

Comment: yes, search.txt is completely controlled: it contains a list of terms that I want to find in my documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-F` and `-P` are conflicting options, simple as that. The first means that the patterns are fixed strings, the second means that the patterns are Perl-compatible regular expressions. Perhaps you meant to use `-f` instead, which reads patterns from a file or a process substitution.

If you want to match any of the patterns in your file, followed by 4 characters, you could use something like this

```
grep -oP -f <(awk '{print $0 ".{4}"}' search.txt) file
```

This dynamically adds the pattern to each line in the file.

Alternatively, a more portable and concise version would be this:

```
sed 's/$/.{0,4}/' search.txt | grep -f - -oP file
```

Comment: I would prefer `sed 's/$/.{0,4}/' search.txt | grep -f - -oP foo.txt` but perhaps it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Both suggestions work. In Cygwin at least the option with `-P` won't work - I get the message "grep: the -P option only supports a single pattern". If `-E` is used instead it will work. What would be the option to search on both sides?

Comment: `sed 's/.*/.{0,4}&.{0,4}/'` adds a predix as well.

Comment: We can't tell if the `-P` is really necessary when we don't know what your patterns look like. If it is, you could smash them all together into one with something like `sed ‘1s/^/.{0,4}(?:/;$!s/\n/|/;$s/$/).{0,4}/'`.

Comment: ... or just switch to Perl (-: or an existing concordance tool, since that seems to be what you are doing?

Comment: @tripleee, both `sed` sugestions work. Yes, it is like a concordancer but I wanted to use `Grep` or `awk` for my task. I know how to write a concordancer in Perl but I'm not sure I'd be able to combine it with an existing search list.